# Chrome extension with no interaction with user

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, content-script, chrome-native-messaging

I am listening to some form events (mouse dbl clicking some elements), raise an event and catch that event in my content script. I do not need any direct interaction with my extension by user. 
Here is my **page.js** (content script):

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage( { method: e.data.methodName, cid: e.data.cbId, jparams: e.data.jsonParams, objectVersion: e.data.objectVersion, objectFile: e.data.objectFile }, function( response ) {
    if( !response ){
        //errCallback();
    }
} );
```

**Popup:**

```
var host_name = "nativeclientapi";
var messageData = null;
var port = null;
// Listen for messages that come from the content script.
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function( request, sender, sendResponse ) {
    if( request) {
        messageData = request;
        alert ('hello');
        sendResponse( { res: 'done!' } );
    }
  } );
```

**Manifest:**

```
{
  "name": "MyChromeExt.Operarations",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "This extension calls a Native API which that API calls some operations.",
  "icons": {
    "128": "icon.png"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "nativeMessaging", "activeTab"
  ],
  "content_scripts" : [{"matches": ["http://localhost/*","https://localhost/*"], "js": ["page.js"]}]
}
```

Why alert is not called? If I add ***browser_action*** to the manifest and set a popup page, then it works, but I do not need to have any interaction with the extension.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it. Simply added a background page to the manifest:

```
  "background": {
    "persistent": false,
    "scripts": ["bg.js"]
  },
```

Comment: Make sure you understand what `"persistent" : false` entails. Your `messageData` will be wiped if the page gets unloaded.

Comment: Actually that variable must be refreshed by every mouse dbl click, so I think it is OK.

Answer (score 1):

> Why alert is not called?

Because with that manifest `popup.js` is not referenced *anywhere*, and never gets loaded. Your extension can have lots of unused files and Chrome will not guess what goes where.

Browser / Page actions are, of course, UI elements. If you don't want a UI (or want a persistent script that's "always there") you need a [**background page**](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages) (or better yet an [event page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages), but make sure you understand the difference).

All in all, take a look at the [Architecture Overview](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#arch).